# X-RequestDigest: Getting error while running recorded web test of sharepoint page

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, performance-testing, load-testing, webtest

I have recorded and replayed my sharepoint webtest successfully but after a week or two, I get '403 FORBIDDEN' error when I replay it in Visual Studio.

I understand that X-RequestDigest has expired certificate/token details and needs to be updated for every run in my request.
However, I'm unable to find preceding X-RequestDigest header value in my recorded web test.

I'm able to extract from response header but I need to bind the value to request prior to response?
Can someone give me a code/method to extract X-RequestDigest header value from Sharepoint page and use it in my Visual Studio Webtest?

Comment: You write *"I'm unable to find preceding X-RequestDigest header value in my recorded web test request section"*. You should be looking for the value in the earlier responses, not in the requests.

Comment: @AdrianHHH: I tried that too..

Comment: Some values are hard to find with Visual Studio. You might perform the script manually and record it with Fiddler then search the Fiddler log for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to your question may vary depends on the version of SharePoint you use. Typically the x-requestdigest value can be extracted from  _api/contextinfo that appears just before the request that you need to parameterize. This is a json response body that looks as follows:

> {"d":{"GetContextWebInformation":{"__metadata":{"type":"SP.ContextWebInformation"},"FormDigestTimeoutSeconds":1800,"FormDigestValue":"0x258D3700E8E516F8E320BAF6FEFDDC271C54C8C44A1E5DBE8B9CBE6ED2A77EDCCF88CAA901790245D3E9B518FB31AA9B345B0E232C93CD39D4E12999499B7414,6
>   Jun 2017 10:26:21
>   -0000","LibraryVersion":"16.0.5521.1202","SiteFullUrl":"https://xxx.sharepoint.com","SupportedSchemaVersions":{"__metadata":{"type":"Collection(Edm.String)"},"results":["14.0.0.0","15.0.0.0"]},"WebFullUrl":"https://xxx.sharepoint.com/Sample_Site"}}}

From here you need to extract the “FormDigestValue” value with an Extract Text extractor. Set the Starts With: "FormDigestValue":"  Ends With: “

If you wish to use Fiddler as AdrianHHH suggested, you may also want to use our free StresStimulus add-on that will create all extractors and parameter automatically as described here http://www.stresstimulus.com/blog/post/visual-studio-load-testing-fixing-playback-errors-in-web-tests. You just need to record the test scenario, save it as a webtest and open in Visual Studio. That way, you don’t have to create any extractors and parameters manually.

Comment: Sharepoint version is 2013. I will definitely try your method and let you know

Comment: got it from contextinfo as you mentioned. I guess I should use stressstimulus add-on to save time :)

Comment: @shenaz, thanks for your update. Sometimes the issue with Visual Studio web performance tests is not only missing extractors and parameters like in your case, but also that some custom headers are by default removed by Visual Studio from recorded requests. Importing webtest from stresstimulus solved both of these issues.