# Data driven works on Performance testing but how will it work on load test

Tags: visual-studio, performance, automation, load-testing, data-driven-tests

I have created Web performance testing using visual studio 2017, Most of the pages are data driven by Login, Change of lists etc is there 
I have added extraction rule, and when i do load test of the same WPT it gives me errors 403 and fail's the test

My question here is how should I make it work

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would need to provide much more information about the tests and what you have already tried to solve the problem. I suggest you do some web searches for terms similar to "debugging visual studio web performance tests".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 403 error usually means that your VS script is failing at login. It is most likely happens due to one or several dynamic values that VS plays back as recorded. To fix it you need to find and manually correlate them by creating extraction rules and parameters somewhere at the beginning of your script. 
It looks like you already created some extractors, but if your script is still failing, chances are that you did not create all of them. Try the manual correlation technique described in my [article](http://www.methodsandtools.com/archive/loadtesterrors2.php).
Or check our Web Test Builder for Visual Studio referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387660/x-requestdigest-getting-error-while-running-recorded-web-test-of-sharepoint-pag) to automatically create missing extractors and parameter.