# Recording Web load test project in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, load-testing

We are trying to record web load test and we are able to successful till we get login page.
After we do login in url, it is getting failed in visual studio.
As login has some authentication token,ids etc.
So how can we get authentication details like token,id etc. In load test project.
 Basically we are doing web performance test through visual studio.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please add a lot more details.

Comment: Basically we are load testing power bi application. We are good till loading the power bi site however its getting failed on authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly noted, one or several tokens/ids causes the issue. VS autocorrelation engine does not appropriately handle them, and they are replayed as recorded instead of using dynamic values generated by the server for each client session in the real-time.

To fix it you need to find and manually correlate such dynamics values by creating extraction rules and parameters, which may be quite time-consuming. Check our Web Test Builder for Visual Studio referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44387660/x-requestdigest-getting-error-while-running-recorded-web-test-of-sharepoint-pag) to create missing extractors and parameter automatically.